# How to use Custom POIs and Custom Data Layers with the HERE SDK in the Flutter?

Tags: flutter, maps, here-api, heremaps

## Preconditions

- Here Explore SDK plan subscribed
- SDK added to the project ad initialised with:

  - accessKeyId
  - accessKeySecret

```dart
Future<void> initializeHERESDK() async {
    SdkContext.init();

    const accessKeyId = "___access_key_id_here___";
    const accessKeySecret = "___access_key_secret_here___";

    final sdkOptions = SDKOptions.withAccessKeySecret(
      accessKeyId,
      accessKeySecret,
    );

    try {
      await SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(sdkOptions);
    } on InstantiationException {
      throw Exception("Failed to initialize the HERE SDK.");
    }
  }
```

- Map is shown
- Search and other built-in methods works with the default HERE data
- BE side uploaded custom POIs to the [enterprise.here.com/#!/layers/](http://enterprise.here.com/#!/layers/) as a Custom Data Layer

## Problem

We’re unable to use Search and use other built-in methods with our Custom POIs / Custom Data Layer.

There are no a possibility to set the Layer to the map or fetch it somehow

## We have tested

- Use searchEngine.searchByAddress() method with an SQL expression as a query parameter:

```dart
Future<void> search() {
    final hereSearchEngine = SearchEngine();

    final query = "SELECT * FROM poi WHERE T2A > 0 AND R > 0";

    final GeoCoordinates areaCenter = GeoCoordinates(
    52.0907, 
    5.1214, 
  );

  final SearchOptions searchOptions = SearchOptions();

  searchOptions.maxItems = 100;

    hereSearchEngine.searchByAddress(
    AddressQuery.withAreaCenter(
      query,
      areaCenter,
    ),
    searchOptions,
    (error, places) {
      if (error != null) {
        print('$error');
      }

      if (places == null || places.isEmpty) {
        print('NO PLACES');
      }

      places?.forEach((place) {
        print('${place.title}');
      });
    },
  );
}
```

Different variations SQL variations have been tested, but in results we’re getting `SearchError.noResultsFound`

- Use MapLayer with a MapLayerBuilder, but didn’t found a way to specify the Custom Layer previously uploaded by the BE to the [enterprise.here.com/#!/layers/](http://enterprise.here.com/#!/layers/)
- Download Custom Layer as .WKT file, parse it and work with the local data, but it’s looks like a wrong solution to work with

## Questions

- How to use Custom Data Layer with a list of Custom POIs directly with the Flutter Here Explore SDK? Code samples?

  - How to set Custom Data Layer as a layer to the HereMap widget or HereMapController?
  - How to separate Custom POIs from the Default ones? So the built-in methods of SDK will be based on the Custom ones? (search through the custom pois, etc.)
  - How to set SQL expression filter to the Custom Layer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the HERE SDK's `SearchEngine` is not supporting SQL syntax. So a query like "SELECT * FROM poi WHERE T2A > 0 AND R > 0" will not be understood.

What you are trying to do sounds like a BYOD use case.

Adding your own data works with the `MyPlaces` API:

```
List<GeoPlace> geoPlaces = [
    GeoPlace.makeMyPlace("Pizza Pino", GeoCoordinates(52.518032, 13.420632)),
    GeoPlace.makeMyPlace("PVR mdh", GeoCoordinates(52.51772, 13.42038)),
    GeoPlace.makeMyPlace("Harley's bar", GeoCoordinates(52.51764, 13.42062))
];

_myPlaces.addPlaces(geoPlaces, (TaskOutcome taskOutcome) {
  if (taskOutcome == TaskOutcome.completed) {
    // Task completed.
  } else {
    // Task cancelled.
  }
});
```

More on this topic can be found in this [guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.14.5.0/dev_guide/topics/search.html#bring-your-own-data).

Note that this requires the `OfflineSearchEngine` which is not supported for the `Explore Edition`.

If you are using a more fancy setup, ie with [custom catalogs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/maps.html#customize-map-data-with-the-catalogconfiguration), then you need to reach-out to HERE directly, as this is not something that will work out-of-the-box for everyone, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Custom POIs and Custom Data layers used to be supported in 3.x but in the latest version which is 4.x it is not supported. As suggested above you can use the BYOD for this.